# can I deploy .net windows application on google cloud?

Tags: vb.net, cloud

I want to deploy .net windows application on Google cloud that performs http request to some http pages and inserts into database.

Comment: I am required to use google cloud to deploy my application which is developed using vb.net so I want to know how to start

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible as google do not support the .Net run-time on the Google App Engine. However there is currently an issue requesting C# support.
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many ways to deploy .NET Applications to Google Cloud as of July, 2018.

.NET *core* applications can be deployed to [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/) and [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/).

.NET *framework* applications can be deployed to [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/).

[Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.GoogleCloudPlatformExtensionforVisualStudio) makes deploying .NET apps to Google Cloud easy.